# List scrolling problem with too many items on iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-listview

I have a large list of data in my local json file. I present this data with the widget structure found below. However, as the list grows on the iOS device, scrolling becomes more difficult. Do you have any solution suggestions for this?

```
class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({super.key});

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _BadgeManagerState();
}

class _A extends State<A> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels >=
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        item.loadPaginatioList();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const AppBarWidget(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
           Slider(),
            const SizedBox(height: 17),
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items!.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => CardItem())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try customScrolView, `shrinkWrap: true,` is not that good